# View does not update when adding items to CoreData until I restart preview

Tags: xcode, swiftui, core-data

I am trying to create a scrollview with circles which can be added or deleted (in SwiftUI using CoreData) but circles do not appear when I create new ones (from another View). Created items appear after I reload the preview. However, deleting them works just fine on its own yet it happens within the View.

How can I fix that?

Here is the code:

**ProfileMenu**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileMenu: View {
    
    @State var circles : [Circle] = []
    @ObservedObject var vm = CircleViewModel()
    
    let colors1 : [Color] = ...
    let colors2 : [Color] = ...
    let colors3 : [Color] = ...
    
    @State var showCircleInfoScreen : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                LazyHStack {
                    ForEach(vm.savedCircles) { circle in
                        createCircle(name: circle ?? "error", isBlue: circle.isBlue)
                        
                    }
                    addCircleButton
                }
            }
            if showCircleInfoScreen {
                CircleView(showCircleInfoScreen: $showCircleInfoScreen)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    var addCircleButton : some View {
        
        Button {
            withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.1)) {
                showCircleInfoScreen.toggle()
            }
            
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Text("ADD")
                    //some modifiers
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                    //some modifiers
                    Text("+")
                    //some modifiers
                }
                .padding(10)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func createCircle(name: String, isBlue: Bool) -> some View  {
        Button {
            //
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Text(name)
                    //some modifiers
                Circle()
                    //some modifiers
                    .overlay {
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                    //some modifiers
                            Text(...)
                        }
                        .contextMenu {
                            Button {
                                vm.deleteCircleInfo(name: name)
                            } label: {
                                Text("Delete info")
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(10)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    struct ProfileMenu_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ProfileMenu()
        }
    }
}
```

**CircleView**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class CircleViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var savedCircles: [Circle] = []
    
    let container : NSPersistentContainer

    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CircleContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR LOADING CORE DATA: \(error)")
            }
        }
        fetchCircleContainer()
    }
    
    func fetchCircleContainer() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Circle>(entityName: "Circle")
        
        do {
            savedCircles = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching. \(error)")
        }
        
    }
    
    func saveCircles() {
        do {
            try container.viewContext.save()
            fetchCircleContainer()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error saving Circle entity. \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func addCircle(name: String, isBlue: Bool) {
        let newCircle = Circle(context: container.viewContext)
        newCircle.name = name
        newCircle.isBlue = isBlue
        saveCircles()
    }
    
    func deleteCircleInfo(name: String) {
        guard let index = savedCircles.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == name}) else { return }
        let entity = savedCircles[index]
        container.viewContext.delete(entity)
        saveCircles()
    }
    
    
}

struct CircleView: View {
    
    @State var textFieldText = ""
    
    @StateObject var vm = CircleViewModel()
    
    @Binding var showCircleInfoScreen : Bool
    
    let colors1 : [Color] = ...
    let colors2 : [Color] = ...
    let colors3 : [Color] = ...
    let colors4 : [Color] = ...
    
    let bgColors : [Color] = ...
    
    @State var selectedColor : String = ""
    @State var isRedColorSelected : Bool = false
    @State var isBlueColorSelected : Bool = false
    @State var selectionReady : Bool = false
    
    @State var circleName : String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Rectangle()
                    //some modifiers
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                Text("CIRCLE INFO")
                    //some modifiers
                Text("NAME")
                    //some modifiers
                TextField(("CIRCLE NAME"), text: $circleName)
                    //some modifiers
                
                Text("COLOR")
                    //some modifiers
                HStack (spacing: 40) {
                    
                    redButton
                    blueButton
                    
                    
                }
                Spacer()
                continueButton
                
            }
            Button {
                withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.3)) {
                    showCircleInfoScreen.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    //some modifiers
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        }
    }
    
    var redButton : some View {
        Button {
            withAnimation(.spring(...)) {
                isRedColorSelected.toggle()
                isBlueColorSelected = false
            }
        } label: {
            Circle()
                //some modifiers
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
        
        
    }
    
    var blueButton : some View {
        Button {
            withAnimation(.spring(...)) {
                isBlueColorSelected.toggle()
                isRedColorSelected = false
            }
        } label: {
            Circle()
                //some modifiers
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
    
    var continueButton : some View {
        
        Button {
            vm.addCircle(name: circleName, isBlue: isBlueColorSelected)
            withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.3)) {
                showCircleInfoScreen.toggle()
            }
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    //some modifiers
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    //some modifiers
                Text("Continue")
                    //some modifiers
                
            }
        }
        .disabled(!(isBlueColorSelected || isRedColorSelected))
    }
}

struct CircleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CircleView(showCircleInfoScreen: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but it's pretty inefficient to re-fetch all records in the `save` method after adding and deleting one. Just insert it accordingly or remove it from the  `savedCircles` array. And be careful not to mix the `savedCircles` property with the `savedCircles` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using two different instances of your view model so the save & delete methods will only update one of the view models.

What you need to do is to create only one instance and then pass it to the other view(s).

First in `CircleView` change the view model to be an `ObservedObject`

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: CircleViewModel
```

and then pass the instance created in `ProfileMenu` to `CircleView`

```
if showCircleInfoScreen {
    CircleView(viewModel: vm, showCircleInfoScreen: $showCircleInfoScreen)
}
```

Comment: I agree with what @vadian writes above in the comments that you should update the array instead but you still need to implement my solution for the updates to be available in different views.